# Can you interact with a web AR scene with A-Frame?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, 8thwall-xr, webxr

Can you interact with a mobile (magic-window) web AR scene in A-Frame, like you can in the 8th Wall demo linked below.

An example: Having three buttons placed on a web AR plane, do you have events on the user pressing one of those?

8th wall demo: https://8thwall.com/web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have interactable entities with the a-frames cursor with it's `rayOrigin` set to `mouse`. For example:

```
<a-marker preset='hiro'>
   <a-box interactable></a-box>
</a-marker>
<a-camera-static cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" />
```

Check it out at [this glitch](https://glitch.com/~aframear-cursor).

---

assuming `interactable` is a custom component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('interactable', {
   init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener('click', e => {
         // magic
      })
   }
})
```